# C++ read file, search for hex, output file

Tags: c++, search, file-io, hex

I can't figure out why this is outputting a different file given that the start of the input file matches the first if statement. Also, if there are multiple finds, the next file name turns out to be the last file name plus the new file name together.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned short n(0);
    unsigned char y;

    std::ostringstream filename;

    std::ifstream input("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    input >> std::noskipws >> std::hex;

    std::ofstream output;
    output << std::ios::binary;

    while (input.good()) {
        filename.clear();
        filename << n << ".dat";
        output.open(filename.str());
        while ( input.good() )
        {
            input >> y;
            output << y;
            if ( y == 0xFF ) {
                input >> y;
                output << y;
                if ( y == 0xD9 ) {
                    input >> y;
                    output << y;
                    output.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (output.is_open())
            output.close();
        ++n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `stringstream.clear()` doesn't empty the stream, it just resets some flags.  Try `stringstream.str("")` instead.

Comment: This fixed the file name issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>  // for input/output
#include <fstream>   // for file stream stuff
#include <sstream>   // for ostringstream

int main()
{
    unsigned short nFile = 0;  // used to increment file name

    std::ostringstream filename;  // output filename

    std::ifstream inFile;      // input stream
    std::ofstream outFile;     // output stream
    unsigned char buffer;      // buffer between input and output

    inFile.open("data.dat", std::ios::binary);  // open input file
    if ( inFile.fail() )
        return 1;

    while ( inFile.good() )
    {
        filename.str("");             // empties the stream
        filename << nFile << ".dat";  // generate filename

        // start the search loop
        while ( inFile.good() )
        {
            // create a file
            outFile.open(filename.str(), std::ios::binary);
            if ( outFile.fail() )
                return 1;

            while ( inFile.good() )
            {
                inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer));  // read a byte
                if ( inFile.eof() )
                    break;
                outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer));  // write a byte
                if ( buffer == 0xFF )
                {
                    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer));  // read a byte
                    if ( inFile.eof() )
                        break;
                    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer));  // write a byte
                    if ( buffer == 0xD9 )  // full match; break loop
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // if search is done and file is still open, close it
            if (outFile.is_open())
                outFile.close();
            ++nFile;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```